# How can I add several languages to my app? not the description

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

My app is in english so everybody should be able to use it. But I also want it to be German as well. And I do NOT mean the description in the store but the app itself.

Do I need to upload a different binary to iTC or is it done by code?

Comment: This is done in your application itself by including multiple translations of your text, and using NSLocalizedString to get the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this tutorial to localize my app. http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

It shows you how to localize both text and images.